# Reference for result on partial sums of Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

I remember seeing somewhere that whenever $f$ is a holomorphic function with radius of convergence at $z$, $0<R<\infty$ the following holds
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(\max_{|w-z|\leq \rho R} |S_n(f,z)(w)|^{1/n})=\rho,$$
where $\rho\geq 1$ and $S_n(f,z)(w)$ is the $n$-th partial sum of the Taylor series of $f$ with center $z$ at $w$.

Does anyone know where I can find the proof of this?